# Integrate C++ gRPC with Bazel on Windows/MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, grpc, bazel

I know that according to [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/5748af6e1876ab9beda827266b2045c89398b7ef/src/cpp), integrating gRPC for C++ using Bazel on Windows is currently not supported, CMake is the preferred way. But since Bazel is very adaptable and gRPC integration works like a charm on Linux I was wondering if there is some example/howto that's not officially supported, ideally for MSVC. I could not find any.

Comment: The README might be out of date, it was modified half a year ago. Have you tried using gRPC with Bazel on Windows? What's the result?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC for C++ doesn't support this yet, although that is indeed the plan, so there is no current example/howto from the team.

You're welcome to try it out and send pull requests for anything you end up patching to make it work. Alternatively, you can create a new feature request at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had success compiling with MSVC/Bazel/gRPC using this rules: https://github.com/stackb/rules_proto/ a few days ago, more thorough testing will happen soon. The above repository allowed for compiling the same code without any modifications for Linux and Windows.